# What do you call the person whom you ship your product to?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, terminology

This person receives your product but they MAY or MAY NOT be your customer (maybe someone who can deliver it to your customer like their relative or friends but *not* some delivery company). Also, their details are added to under 'Shipping Details' by the customer maybe because your customer doesn't have a permanent address yet.

What do you call this person? Some names I thought of were 'receiver' or 'referee' or 'trustee' but I don't think they're accurate enough in business terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this person actually has their name and address as the "Ship To" address then they may be referred to as the ***addressee*** (the one to whom it is addressed).

Alternatively, the package may be addressed to your customer in the *care of* some ***intermediary***.

From [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/care_of):

> *Care of*, usually abbreviated as c/o on envelopes, signifies an **intermediary<sup>*</sup>** who is responsible for transferring a piece of mail between the postal system and the final addressee. For example, when the addressee has no standard address, is under a corporate mail system, or is being manually forwarded mail sent to a more accessible location.

<sub>* *emphasis mine*</sub>

Answer (score 9):

A *recipient* (as defined by say [Lexico](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/recipient))
is what you call someone who receives something. It would fit the context.

Answer (score 7):

Since you are specifically talking about shipping a product sold, another often-used term is [***consignee***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/consign?q=consignee#consign__11), an *-ee* derivation to the verb *consign* (same link, def. 1.1):

> Send (goods) by a public carrier.

The consignee of a package is the person to whom it is addressed. Unlike *recipient* and *addressee* (which are both perfectly valid words for this, but also have broader meanings in other contexts), *consignee* is very rarely, if ever, used to refer to anything but specifically the recipient of a (commercial) shipment or package.

Answer (score 0):

**Recipient**

***Dictionary.com:***

> a person or thing that receives; receive

***Cambridge dictionary:***

> a person who receives something

***Merriem-Webster:***

> one that receives : RECEIVER

***Vocabulary.com:***

> the person on the receiving end of something.

***Macmillan:***

> someone who receives something

Comment: Hello, hossein. Didn't you see that Cerberus has already given this answer?